# Checking if object is of certain type in GSP

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a list of domain objects in GSP view and would like to check if any of them are of particular type:

```
Class Equipment {}
Class Loader extends Equipment {}
```

... in view:

```
<g:each in="${Equipment.list()}" var="e">
   ... check if e is a Loader....
</g:each>
```

I'm trying to do the check if a GSP fragment to build a nav menu and wonder if this even the right spot to do the check in.

Comment: I would do such checks in a controller and render different partial templates for the sub-types, myself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're making the logic in a GSP complex like that you should consider creating a taglib instead. It'll be easy to test too - GSPs need to be tested with functional tests and a running web server, but you can test taglibs with integration tests.

Comment: Hi Burt, not being a smart-ass, but what makes that complex?

Comment: It's a judgement call, but my preference is to not do much more than looping in a GSP. If I end up doing any logic, I'm going to move it to a taglib. GSPs should be very dumb and just render HTML.

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
<g:each in="${Equipment.list()}" var="e">
     <g:if test="${e instanceof your.package.Loader}">Do anything</g:if>
</g:each>
```